# Sum values in nested dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

I have a list of dictionary:

```
data = [
    {"2010" : {'A' : 2,'B' : 3,'C' : 5,}},    
    {"2011" : {'A' : 1,'B' : 2,}},
    {"2010" : {'A' : 1,'B' : 2,}}
]
```

I'd like sum the values where the key is same. So the result I expected should be like this:

```
res =
    {"2010" : {'A' : 3, 'B' : 5, 'C' : 5},
     "2011" : {'A' : 1, 'B' : 2}}
```

How can I do this easily?

Comment: you can not have a dict with the same key repeating

Comment: Keys are always unique in python `dict`. Your `data` is impossible to reproduce unless it's a list or some data structure that can hold duplicate values.

Comment: sorry, that's true, i was inaccurate. its a list of dictionaries.

Comment: res is a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

So you have a list of dictionaries as input and you want to create an output dictionary which contains the sums:

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = [{'2010': {'A': 2, 'B': 3, 'C': 5}}, {'2011': {'A': 1, 'B': 2}}, {'2010': {'A': 1, 'B': 2}}]

def sum_values(data):
    out = {}
    for i in data:
        for k in i.keys():
            if k not in out:
                out[k] = defaultdict(int)
            for k1,v1 in i[k].items():
                out[k][k1] += v1
    return out

sum_values(data)
{'2010': defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'A': 3, 'B': 5, 'C': 5}), '2011': defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'A': 1, 'B': 2})}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
data = [
    { "2010":{'A':2,'B':3,'C':5,}},    
    { "2011":{'A':1,'B':2,}},
    {"2010":{'A':1,'B':2,}}
]

res = {}

for d in data:
    # print(d.items())
    items = list(d.items())[0]  # convert to list because dict items isn't subscriptable
    year, value = items
    if year not in res:
        res[year] = value
```

`res` is equal to

```
{
    '2010': {'A': 2, 'B': 3, 'C': 5},
    '2011': {'A': 1, 'B': 2}
}
```